# Pcap parser with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

i want to write a small program that can extract Host IP, OS , Open ports , and all identified protocols in a list based on the number of open ports on each host

that's my first task and i don't know where to start could you please help or just give me some guide lines ?

i tried to use Scapy or Pyshark but my very little exp couldn't help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you meet so you can get proper help from the community.

Comment: You can start by having a look at scapy’s doc: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ it’s pretty well done for beginners